# Internally Redirect URL without 302 status using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am new to PHP. I created a website which creates a multiplication table from given input number.
Now I want that instead of submitting the input, a number multiplication table should be accessible through URL.
i.e. www.multiply.com/multiplication-of-13.php.
Creating a single page for every doesn't seem like a feasible solution,
So I did it using the .htaccess file by changing the query parameter to URL.

Example :

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^multiplication\-of\-([0-9]+)\.php$ index.php?num=$1 [R]
```

Now the problem is this configuration is generating 302 redirect, which is not suitable for SEO, and if I use [R=301] then the changes reflect in the URL, which does not seem user-friendly, Is there is any possible solution that the URL redirection doesn't return HTTP Code 302?

Comment: Don't use R then?  I don't see a need for a redirect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take off the `[R]` after the URL. That means "redirect," which is explicitly what you are asking not to happen.

Comment: Thanks, made it using combing multiple answers, a new URL was generated, I thought [R] would be required for redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The [R] in your rewrite is causing it to generate a 302.

```
RewriteRule ^multiplication\-of\-([0-9]+)\.php$ index.php?num=$1 [L, QSA]
```

Comment: As there are no query parameters in the source URL, I don't think there will any need of QSA flag!

Comment: True, just copied the laravel apache rewrite honestly. I've never used apache, only nginx so I'm a tad ignorant on it.